# Decoding a JSON error in Flutter, type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: json, flutter, mobile

I've got the same error  `type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'`, I had with a previous API call and I was able to fix it but declaring properties in the model to be `final dynamic` instead of `final int` or `final String`, but this time I tried almost everything and can't seems to resolve this issue when trying to decode the response from the API call

The API call:

```
 Future<HTTPResponse<List<UserData>>> getUser() async {
    final response =
        await LcHttp.apiRequest(Method.GET, '/users/' + this._loggedUserEmail, this._jsonWebToken);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      List<UserData> posts = [];
      body.forEach((e) {
        UserDatapost = UserData.fromJson(e);
        posts.add(post);
      });
      return HTTPResponse<List<UserData>>(
        true,
        posts,
        message: 'Request Successful',
        statusCode: response.statusCode,
      );
    } else {
      print('Error occurred! Data is not fetched!');
    }
  }
}
```

The Data model:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class UserData extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String name, email;

  UserData ({
    this.name,
    this.email
  });

  factory UserData .fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserData (
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

The body response:

```
"data":[{"name":"Loki","email":"jotun@heim.com"}]
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: There is a space between UserData and post in  UserDatapost = UserData.fromJson(e); right? in the forEach

Comment: Yes, there is must've copied the code wrong so it showed that there is no space.